# Cropping UIImage Complications in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I'm currently cropping an UIImage with my 
`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method like so:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2448, 3264);

    UIImage *croppedImage = [img crop:cropRect];

    imageToPass = croppedImage;

    NSLog(@"Here's imageToPass: %@", imageToPass);
    NSLog(@"and here's imageToPass' width: %f", imageToPass.size.width);
    NSLog(@"and here's imageToPass' height: %f", imageToPass.size.height);
    NSLog(@"and here's imageToPass' scale: %f", imageToPass.scale);

    UINavigationController *postControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postControl"];
    RGPostViewController *postView = (RGPostViewController *)postControl.topViewController;

    [postView storeImage:imageToPass];

    [self.presentedViewController presentViewController:postControl animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

My problem is that when I print the width and height of my `imageToPass` variable I find that the value is listed in points. My console prints like this:

[image]

I need to get an image returned that is cropped to be 320x320 in size. With my code `CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2448, 3264);` Im taking the original size of the photo, which by default with **UIImagePickerController** is, I'm assuming, 320x520 or something like that. Using point values I can see that 2448 is the points wide and 3264 is the height. From Google,

> iPhone 5 display resolution is 1136 x 640 pixels. Measuring 4 inches diagonally, the new touch screen has an aspect ratio of 16:9 and is branded a Retina display with 326 ppi (pixels per inch).

Im not sure what to do here. Does the math `2448points/640px = 3.825` tell me that there is 3.825 points per pixel on a 326ppi screen?

PS keep in mind I'm trying to grab the 320x320 picture in the middle of the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` which means cutting of some top number of pixels and some bottom number of pixels determined in points I'm assuming.

**EDIT**

Here's the code for the `crop:` method in the fourth line of code above:

```
#import "UIImage+Crop.h"

@implementation UIImage (Crop)

- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect {

    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*self.scale,
                      rect.origin.y*self.scale,
                      rect.size.width*self.scale,
                      rect.size.height*self.scale);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                                          scale:self.scale
                                    orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}

@end
```

I have found that if I set my `CGRect cropRect` with `CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(264, 0, 2448, 3000); //3264` it actually removes 264 points from the top and bottom of the image. I understand that an iPhone 5s has a screen resolution of 326ppi(pixels per inch), how can I use this to successfully remove the amount of pixels that I need to remove.

Comment: This should be really a lot easier than it is

Comment: Do you mean you want a 320x320 point square from the center of your image or do you mean you want to crop your image so it's square?

Comment: I want to crop my image to be perfectly square. Im not even sure what it means for an image to be 320x320. Since it says that the screen is 640x1136, divide those by two and you get 320x568 which is actually how the views are in the Storyboard file. Totally confused with all these measurements but I just simply need to cut off the top and bottom of my UIImagePickerController to "squaresize" an image.

Comment: In that case  I would edit your question and remove all references to 320x320 because people are trying to answer using that information. And the ppi is a red herring too! I would just say 'How do I crop a UIImage to make it square' and see what answers you get.

Comment: And this is probably helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203951/cropping-center-square-of-uiimage

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know about converting points/pixels/retina/non/etc because of a property of the screen called `scale`. You do need to use core graphics to do the actual crop though. Here's what it could look like:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {   
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // you want to make your rect in the center of your image, not at [0,0]
    CGFloat cropSize = 320;
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(img.center.x - (cropSize / 2), img.center.y - (cropSize / 2), cropSize, cropSize);

    // Make a new CGImageRef with the current graphics context, then use that to make the cropped UIImage. Make sure to release that image ref!
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], cropRect);
    croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    // Adjust the image for scale - this is how you handle retina/orientation.
    imageToPass = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                      scale:self.scale 
                                orientation:self.imageOrientation];

    UINavigationController *postControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postControl"];
    RGPostViewController *postView = (RGPostViewController *)postControl.topViewController;

    [postView storeImage:imageToPass];

    [self.presentedViewController presentViewController:postControl animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is completely wrong lol.

Comment: How so? Did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

The answer i've posted will give you a 320x320 crop of the center.

Comment: Well, first of all, there is no such property "center.x" of a UIImage. If you change this to `img.size.width/2` it still does not work. Same with `center.y`.. doesn't exist. Also, when setting **imageToPass** with `scale` and `orientation`, you cannot use self.scale and self.imageOrientation as 'self' is not an UIImage. Therefore, that must be changed to be either croppedImage.scale, etc. or img.scale etc. Oh! and the `CGRect cropRect` does not need width and height of `cropSize = 320` as it is measured in points, not 320. As I said, the originalImage is CGRectMake(0, 0, 2448, 3264);

Comment: You're right, pardon my mis-typing. Adapted this from a crop controller I recently worked up, and had properties already defined for scale and image orientation. Scale can be determined through: `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`

Comment: Actually no... `scale` and `imageOrientation` are both properties of UIImage... so just change `self.scale` to `img.scale`. Sorry for the typo.

I'm also not sure why you're hard-coding the image size. Are all your images forever going to be the same?

The pixel size of your crop is a combination of your defined size (cropRect) and your scale.

Comment: Oh ok. Hold on check my edit. I'm not too sure why I'm hard coding it either other than Im just trying to get my images taken by the UIImagePickerController to be taken at a certain height. Of which, I think I could do by using a customOverlay. Im just really confused as to what's going on here as I don't really know what Im doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82658/discussion-between-chris-slowik-and-chisx).