# Can't scale image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have a small UITableViewCell and a huge UIImage(as on image).

[image]

I have to make this image as a background of my cell. I want to scale my image to make its width equal to cell width. Then I want to display small piece from this image(this piece should be cropped from the middle), the height of this piece should be equal to the height of my UITableViewCell. 
I tried to play with scaleMode of my cell background view, but nothing positive happened( Could you please help me to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203951/cropping-center-square-of-uiimage  Look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Pin your UIImage to all 4 edges of your TableViewCell content. Then with UIImage selected set it's view mode to Aspect Fill. I believe that will cover the image to the width of the cell and crop from the centerpoint.

[image]

Comment: I even couldn't expect, that the solution will be so beautiful and easy...) It's working!)

Comment: @YuraChukhlib load  images so big in table view cells will probably make crash your application for memory pressures or poor performance during scrolling. The right way is scale them by redrawing and then add to the image view

Comment: @Andrea In my case such problems won't appear, but in general you are right!

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `contentMode` property of your `UIImageView`.
`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` looks fine for you according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@UIViewContentMode) :

> **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill** :
>
> The option to scale the content to fill the size of the view. Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.